# Jquery AJAX method works only in IE

Tags: jquery

Here is my jquery AJAX method which works in Ie only but not in chrome or firefox. My code is

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2">     
 </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://50.116.19.49/rest/user.json",
            success: function(result) {
                $("div").text(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>
<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the server file is in the same Ip?

Comment: Have you tried a more recent version of jQuery?  Any console errors?

Comment: Both files are on different ips

Comment: yes i have tried different versions but no use.

Comment: then you cannot use json.. u should use jsonp to communicate with different servers. because cross server ajax calls are not allowed in firefox & chrome

Answer (score 0):

You need JSONP. Luckily for you jQuery comes with some good support for it. See this IBM article:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [jquery.xdomainajax.js](https://raw.github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js)

Remeber to explicitly `type GET` it.

```
    $("button").click(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://50.116.19.49/rest/user.json",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(result) {
            $("div").text(result.responseText);
        }
    });
});​
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KNfVz/1/).

Comment: your code is working perfectly on fiddle but when i copy it to my local machine it stops working. Any comments

Comment: You are forgetting to include the xdomainajax.js